# IBM Cloud Certificate Manager: Unable to retrieve a list of certificates

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-certificate-manager

Trying to `GET` a list of certificates from my IBM Cloud Certificate Manager service instance fails with:

```
{
  "code": "COMERR400-03",
  "message": "Invalid parameter value",
  "additionalInfo": {
    "field": "instance_id"
  }
}
```

I used [this Swagger endpoint](https://us-south.certificate-manager.bluemix.net/docs/#/Certificates/list) for my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, the problem was that I supplied the `instanceId` parameter as a `UUID` instead of a `CRN`.

I've used the value, e.g. `1974bc1b-4a00-4d4a-b19a-1ba66077e5d2` instead of e.g.,
 `crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloudcerts:us-south:a/*****:1974bc1b-4a00-4d4a-b19f-1ba66077e1d2::`.

To find out the correct CRN value I used this IBM Cloud CLI command:

```
bx resource service-instance "my-instance-name" --id
```